# rDEA: why do I get negative theta from Data Envelopment Analysis?

Tags: r

I am using the package rDEA in R to perform an input-oriented Data Envelopment Analysis. From my understanding, the resulting efficiency coefficient theta should be in the [0, 1] range by construction(?). However, some of the coefficients I obtain are negative and/or with confidence intervals outside the range. How is this possible? Am i doing something wrong?

Here is my code, including the exact data I am using (all variables have been divided by their cross-section mean to bring them to common scale):

```
## Import libraries
library(data.table)
library(fastpipe)
library(rDEA)

inputs <- structure(list(exp = c(1.45631953364524, 1.66436627311178, 
                                 0.49196775193678, 2.3921923224414, 0.566080570390277, 1.52765097750528, 
                                 1.27803808944191, 1.04608131903838, 0.503721239512992, 0.36355050866804, 
                                 1.54003174549243, 0.954059544697017, 0.446706427106333, 0.366260202876539, 
                                 3.14166782031816, 1.57819541789705, 0.359730199930916, 0.685481093042031, 
                                 0.344358655709796, 2.33037483179135)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
                                 ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

outputs <- structure(list(re = structure(c(0.987838685512543, 1.00511574745178, 
                                       0.999720394611359, 1.02197182178497, 1.06660687923431, 1.06061482429504, 
                                       1.00458967685699, 1.01615834236145, 0.932821154594421, 0.970696270465851, 
                                       1.05653548240662, 0.971303999423981, 0.976226985454559, 0.970465421676636, 
                                       0.95845764875412, 0.988636434078217, 1.04384517669678, 1.00294649600983, 
                                       0.933982729911804, 1.03146553039551)), 
               mat = structure(c(1.00566446781158, 1.02406275272369, 
                                    1.00672328472137, 1.02673959732056, 1.05499053001404, 1.02251279354095, 
                                    0.998539805412292, 1.00788450241089, 0.909778714179993, 0.969666600227356, 
                                    1.00705635547638, 0.980766892433167, 0.999988555908203, 0.969885349273682, 
                                    0.974380731582642, 1.04655814170837, 1.03933596611023, 0.992653965950012, 
                                    0.979910254478455, 1.01260888576508)), 
               sci = structure(c(0.996497690677643, 1.01479399204254, 
                                       1.01076185703278, 1.00230967998505, 1.07854735851288, 1.06181609630585, 
                                       1.00300145149231, 1.0233713388443, 0.918883144855499, 0.978453516960144, 
                                       1.00938296318054, 0.952207505702972, 0.991350531578064, 0.980804085731506, 
                                       0.970025718212128, 1.02417480945587, 1.03974294662476, 1.0003570318222, 
                                       0.94414210319519, 1.01616036891937))),
               row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) 

dmus <- 1:20

model <- dea.robust(X=inputs, Y=outputs, model="input", RTS="variable",
                    B=1000, alpha=0.05)

# Merge results
results <- data.table(dmus,
                      model[["theta_hat_hat"]],
                      model[["theta_ci_low"]],
                      model[["theta_ci_high"]]) %>%
  setorder(., -V2)
colnames(results)[2] <- "theta_hat"
colnames(results)[3] <- "ci_low"
colnames(results)[4] <- "ci_high"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no issue with the data and no issue with the rDEA package.

Negative theta_hat_hat can naturally happen with Simar and Wilson's 1998 method because this method subtracts the estimated bias.

For further discussion see: https://github.com/jaak-s/rDEA/issues/20

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the rDEA package.

Answer (score 0):

I know that based on some documentation, like below link, the value for "theta_hat_hat" is said to be between 0 and 1:

https://rdrr.io/cran/rDEA/man/dea_robust.html

But above link didn't refer to actual theta hat which should be between 0 and 1. if you read the official documentation in github repository for dea.robust() in this link:

https://github.com/cran/rDEA/blob/master/R/dea.robust.R

you will find that theta_hat is "original DEA efficiency score" and theta_hat_hat is "bias corrected efficiency scores". The value for theta_hat is between 0 and 1 and value for theta_hat_hat is not necessarily between 0 and 1. Therefore, I corrected your code as below and in the result, you will see theta_hat is between 0 and 1.

```
## Import libraries
library(data.table)
library(fastpipe)
library(rDEA)


inputs <- structure(list(exp = c(1.45631953364524, 1.66436627311178, 
                                 0.49196775193678, 2.3921923224414, 0.566080570390277, 1.52765097750528, 
                                 1.27803808944191, 1.04608131903838, 0.503721239512992, 0.36355050866804, 
                                 1.54003174549243, 0.954059544697017, 0.446706427106333, 0.366260202876539, 
                                 3.14166782031816, 1.57819541789705, 0.359730199930916, 0.685481093042031, 
                                 0.344358655709796, 2.33037483179135)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
                                 ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


outputs <- structure(list(re = structure(c(0.987838685512543, 1.00511574745178, 
                                       0.999720394611359, 1.02197182178497, 1.06660687923431, 1.06061482429504, 
                                       1.00458967685699, 1.01615834236145, 0.932821154594421, 0.970696270465851, 
                                       1.05653548240662, 0.971303999423981, 0.976226985454559, 0.970465421676636, 
                                       0.95845764875412, 0.988636434078217, 1.04384517669678, 1.00294649600983, 
                                       0.933982729911804, 1.03146553039551)), 
               mat = structure(c(1.00566446781158, 1.02406275272369, 
                                    1.00672328472137, 1.02673959732056, 1.05499053001404, 1.02251279354095, 
                                    0.998539805412292, 1.00788450241089, 0.909778714179993, 0.969666600227356, 
                                    1.00705635547638, 0.980766892433167, 0.999988555908203, 0.969885349273682, 
                                    0.974380731582642, 1.04655814170837, 1.03933596611023, 0.992653965950012, 
                                    0.979910254478455, 1.01260888576508)), 
               sci = structure(c(0.996497690677643, 1.01479399204254, 
                                       1.01076185703278, 1.00230967998505, 1.07854735851288, 1.06181609630585, 
                                       1.00300145149231, 1.0233713388443, 0.918883144855499, 0.978453516960144, 
                                       1.00938296318054, 0.952207505702972, 0.991350531578064, 0.980804085731506, 
                                       0.970025718212128, 1.02417480945587, 1.03974294662476, 1.0003570318222, 
                                       0.94414210319519, 1.01616036891937))),
               row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) 



dmus <- 1:20

model <- dea.robust(X=inputs, Y=outputs, model="input", RTS="variable",
                    B=1000, alpha=0.05)


# Merge results
results <- data.table(dmus,
                      model[["theta_hat"]],
                      model[["theta_hat_hat"]],
                      model[["theta_ci_low"]],
                      model[["theta_ci_high"]]) %>%
  


  setorder(., -V2)
colnames(results)[2] <- "theta_hat"
colnames(results)[3] <- "theta_hat_hat"
colnames(results)[4] <- "ci_low"
colnames(results)[5] <- "ci_high"

results
```

The result is as below (consider theta_hat column).

[image]